# How to replace row values with column name in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 1271 columns and 306 rows. Barring the first column, all other columns have either a value "0" or "1". What I want to do is replace all the "1" 's in my entire matrix with the respective column name. Can someone help me?

Comment: @user3114046 - nice fix - **that's** what the problem with this post was - capitalization

Comment: Matrices don't have `dimnames` unless specified.  What are the column names?

Answer (score 0):

Just remember that a matrix can only hold one data type: either all numeric or all character. So replacing with column names will force everything to all character. But here's a sample on a matrix with 12 columns and 5 rows.

```
#sample data
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 12*5, replace=T), ncol=12)
colnames(m)<-letters[1:ncol(m)]

#replacement
ones <- which(m==1, arr.ind=T)
m[ones]<-colnames(m)[ones[,2]]
m;
```

Comment: "Barring the first column, all other columns have either a value "0" or "1". "

Comment: @RichardScriven I guess this is only a problem if the first column contains 1's. I figure it should be easy to adapt to the real data. When there is no sample data provided, it's hard to know exactly what will work and how.